# Can the reader account consume data from the other producers than the one that created it?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Let's assume there are two snowflake accounts called A & B. A created a reader account called C and also shared some objects. Now, Can the snowflake account B share the objects to reader account C?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Each reader account belongs to the provider account that created it. A reader account can **only** consume data from the provider account that created it.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-sharing-intro.html#reader-accounts

Answer (score 0):

No, it cannot be used for data sharing from another account.

Comment: Great! Thanks, Gokhan & Srinath!

Comment: One more quick question. What is the recommended file size for data loading through snowpipe? I read it's 100-250 MB in one place and 10-100 MB in another. Which one of them is true?

Comment: It is recommended to be 100-250 MB and this update happened around a year back when it used to be suggested to have 10-100 MB.

Comment: Wow! This is great info! Much helpful